# Why is Racket evaluating both of these functions in one case, but not the other?

Tags: functional-programming, racket, side-effects

Defining the function `my-if` to use `cond` internally results in different behavior than using `cond` directly.

Using `cond`, the DrRacket interpreter only prints the string for the first `displayln`.

Code:

```lisp
(cond
  (#t (displayln "Cond: should run"))
  (else (displayln "Cond: shouldn't run")))
```

Output:

```
Cond: should run
```

Using `my-if`, the DrRacket interpreter prints both of the strings, despite seeming (at least to me) that it should expand to the same code.

Code:

```lisp
(define (my-if condition statement-if statement-else)
  (cond (condition statement-if)
        (else statement-else)))

(my-if
 #t
 (displayln "My-If: should run")
 (displayln "My-If: shouldn't run"))
```

Output:

```
My-If: should run
My-If: shouldn't run
```

I assumed that the function created by `define` would expand to the same code as the `cond`, but given that it has a different result, I assume it didn't.

Given that the 2 versions of the code have different results, my guess is something related to eager/lazy evaluation or `cond` being a macro in and of itself.

Comment: Yes, a function is not a macro.

Comment: All arguments of a function are evaluated, then the function is. You need a macro.

Comment: ["A function call is evaluated by first evaluating the proc-expr and all arg-exprs in order (left to right)"](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html)

Comment: A function does not "expand"; `(my-if e0 e1 e2)` is more or less equivalent to `(let ((x e0) (y e1) (z e2)) (cond (x y) (else z)))`, not `(cond ((e0 e1) (else e2)))`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, those are expressions, not statements.

Comment: Also, it only looks like both branches are evaluated because the result of `println` is not displayed in the REPL. In Racket, compare `(println "Hello")` to `(print (println "Hello"))`; or do `(define x (println "Hello"))` and compare `x` to `(print x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Function application in Racket is evaluated in the following way:

- evaluate the function
- evaluate the arguments
- apply the function to the arguments

Since you're writing `(my-if #t (displayln "should") (displayln "shouldn't"))`, each of the arguments (including both `displayln`s) are evaluated first.

This is why you can't define conditionals as a function. What you're really looking for is Racket's macro system. You can then define `my-if` as a macro in the following way:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (my-if c t e)
  (cond
    [c t]
    [else e]))

(my-if #t (displayln "should run") (displayln "shouldn't run"))
```

Note that unlike function application, which evaluates the arguments first, a macro is actually expanded syntactically (in Racket, also [hygenically](https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/hygiene.html)).